# feedback loop for a single stage offline flyback that is powering 2 independent LED strings

Tags: power-supply, flyback, control-loop

I have a design that is a offline, single stage flyback, powering two different LED strings.  The output of this converter is about 50W and the output voltage can range from 20V-45V.  I'm using ST Micro's HVLED001A control IC, if it matters.  Each LED string can be commanded by the user to have a different amount of current.  So, I need to both regulate the current through each string, and then also make sure I have enough output voltage to drive the current I want.  The scheme I've come up with is -

[image: Control Loop Scheme]

(I've only shown the feedback loop for one of the strings, but Vb1 and CS1 connect to an identical circuit connect to an identical circuit to the one Q4 is driven by)
Unfortunately, control loop design is not a strong point of mine, and I'm not getting it to function the way I want.  The U5 opamp (on the right of the picture) will control the Q4 BJT such that I get the current I want through the string.  The feedback loop to the primary side, though, is causing me some problems.  What I want to do is look at Vx1 and Vx2 - the cathodes of each of the LED strings - and guarantee that I have at least 1V at either location.  The opamps U1 and U3 control BJTs Q1 and Q2, in series with the optocoupler.  If either Vx1 or Vx2 is below 1V, the optocoupler will have no current going through it.

Because this is a single stage, offline flyback, I need to not have the loop respond to 120Hz ripple on the output.  What I want to see at Vx1 and Vx2 is a 1V average with some amount of 120Hz ripple on top of that.  However, my circuit is holding the output steady, rather than allowing that ripple.  I assume that means that my loop bandwidth is too fast, but I'm unsure what to do about it.  I've attempted increasing the C1 and C3 caps around the opamps from 1uF to 3uF to no avail.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: That circuit is too small and fragmented. Try making it more readable and try joining wires up instead of using node names. Nobody here has the benefit of clicking on a wire and highlighting other wires on the same net. For instance, I can't see where FVR comes from AND to make it smaller you can dispense with most of one channel's circuitry.

Comment: I'll also point out that you've raised 4 questions now and haven't paid the usual fee to the best answer - the fee is you select the answer that is most appropriate to you and formally "accept" it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use the site all that often, and just added comments to let the person know when they helped, but I went back and paid the fee on my previous questions.

Comment: I'll update the schematic.  I was trying to break it into functional chunks rather than having all the nodes connected, but I can understand how that might be confusing.  FVR was actually an oversight - I had meant to remove that.  It's the fixed voltage reference coming from a microcontroller that allows me to change the set point of that portion of the feedback loop.

Comment: Happy days especially as one of those answers was mine!

Comment: Hopefully, that's an easier schematic to look at.  It's still a bit small, but I wanted to keep the circuitry for both BJTs in series with the opto in case there was some issue with having two circuits connected like that.

Comment: Add a series resistor between the vdd divider and U1 negative terminal, that will slow your error amplifier down (move the pole towards DC)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to read if you compacted it more like this: -

[image]

> What I want to see at Vx1 and Vx2 is a 1V average with some amount of
>   120Hz ripple on top of that. However, my circuit is holding the output
>   steady, rather than allowing that ripple. I assume that means that my
>   loop bandwidth is too fast, but I'm unsure what to do about it. I've
>   attempted increasing the C1 and C3 caps around the opamps from 1uF to
>   3uF to no avail.

C7 and R22 will begin to have an effect around 1 kHz. At lower frequencies than this the loop gain will be high so, try making C1 around 10 uF and see what happens. Alternatively, low pass filter the signal coming from the 0.1 ohm shunt resistor R10.

You could also try shunting R23 with a 22 uF capacitor. Don't do all the mods or it'll turn into an oscillator more than likely.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried a couple of those things with no luck.  The U5 circuit functions as intended.  I want U5 to react quickly, to keep the current through the LEDs steady.  R10's voltage should have no ripple - U5 having a rolloff at 1kHz is desired.

Comment: U3 is the stage that needs to disregard the 120Hz ripple.  C3 and R7 were picked such that it would have a bandwidth around 20Hz.  Increasing C3 by 3x changes very little though, so the circuit must not be behaving the way I expect.  I've tried putting a 10uF from U3+ to ground, in order to LP filter Vx2, but that causes Q2 to just rapidly turn on and off.  Increase R13 to try and help that has no effect.  Is having the input to the U3 stage on the positive terminal of the opamp, but the AC feedback going to the negative terminal going to cause an issue?

Comment: If there is ripple on the LED anodes then there should be the same ripple at Vx1 and Vx2. If there is no ripple at Vx1 and Vx2 then there is likely no ripple. However, you seem to be thinking (in the passage I copied) that the U5 circuit will hold it constant but, on further reflection, it won't - whatever ripple is on the anode will be on the cathode (in order to keep the current constant) so, maybe you have no ripple but, then you talk about wanting to disregard the ripple so I'm now officially confused as to what it is you want and what it is you see/measure.

Comment: Heh - I'm sure you feel like what I feel like when my parents wants me to do tech support over the phone for them.

Comment: I want ripple on the output; I do not have it because U3 holds Vx2 at a constant 1V, which means the LED anodes are also at a constant voltage.  I want Vx2 to be held to an average of 1V and for U3 to integrate out any 120Hz ripple on that signal.